# How to lock the navigation position while resizing widow?

Tags: css, browser, navigation

I got this problem for my drop down menu, I was trying to set my navigation to position: absolute, however when I do that, it messed up....does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Here's my page:http://calibredesign.com/clients/harmony/

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: It's pretty hard to resize a widow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following to the `nav bar` will do the trick:

```
min-width: 900px;
```